# In Angular2/SystemJS, what are the relationships in systemjs.config.js and .import()?

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to get into Angular2. I have read a few Stack Exchange posts, and a few internet articles, about what systemjs.config.js is doing. However, I find that all of these explanations use the word "app" too many times.

When index.html says:

```
<script>
 System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

.. what is the 'app' argument? My sample config file has 3 objects, 2 of which have "app" keys, and one of which even has an "app" value for the "app" key. In addition, there is an "app" folder, which I'm sure is not a coincidence. On top of that there are plenty of files that begin with the word "app" (app.module.ts, etc), but all of those live in the app folder, so I don't know if they matter.

I have tried changing to .import('app2'), but the only thing I can figure out that does not cause a break is to change the map key to app2 ( map: { app2: "app" }). But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to change the other things. I've tried changing the folder name, the keys, and the values. So for example, the following does not work (even if I change the app folder to app2 or app3):

```
map: {
    app2: "app3"
}
packages: {
    app3: { ... }
}
```

Can someone please explain, in plain English, the order of these things and how they relate?

PS: This post [Can anyone explain systemjs.config.js in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507183/can-anyone-explain-systemjs-config-js-in-angular2) was very helpful in explaining what the rest of the "map" object was doing, and the "paths" object as well, but it does not explain the part I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

COMPLETE EDIT:
OK. After tons more experimenting and research, I have discovered this:

There are 3 things that need to match: System.import's **argument**, the key name in systemjs.config's **map** object, and the key name in systemjs.config's **packages** object. You can name them anything you want, as long as they all match.

map's key's value must point to a folder, and package's key's value's "main" key must point to a file in that folder.

I will explore the following further:

1. system.config's map's key must point to a RELATIVE folder, but relative to "index.html" (where system.config.js is called), or relative to systemjs.config.js?

--ANSWER: relative to index.html

2. In systemjs.config.js, there are several maps: "app", "rxjs", and a bunch of @angular ones. However, only the "app" and "rxjs" have matching packages. Why don't the "@angular/*" maps need their own packages?

-- ?

3. Actually, does packages.app.main need to point to a file within the folder identified by map.main? It looks like that path can be relative as well ...

-- ANSWER: Yes this path can be relative, and can even go "up" ("../").

4. If you use tsconfig.outDir (which is usually quite nice with the map.app property), AND you have a TS file "above" the outDir (for example, in the project root), then outDir will "shift" its output.

-- ANSWER: So, if your ts files are in "app" folder, and you use outDir to "dist" folder, and you have a "test.ts" file in your root, then you cannot use {outDir: dist}. Instead, you have to use {outDir: dist/app}.